# How to create timer button in android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments

I want to ask, if there is a way to create a button, which will show, how much time you have, to make an action.

### Example:

### 0:60s

after 60s, some action will happen, but the button will always show the time, which is "left" until an action happens.

Does any have some experience/tips for me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to replace the button text with timer text , that's it !

Here is some useful [code](https://codinginflow.com/code-examples/android/countdown-timer/part-1)